# get column information after being hidden by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty **huge** table, with filter and hide/unhide options. The hide/unhide option will also hide/unhide the ID column as well. Before, I was tracking the columns ID as follows

## jQuery

```
var ids = [];
$('#example tr td:first-child').each(function(i){
    ids.push($(this).text());
});
```

## html

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th id='ID'>ID</th>
        <th id='Email'>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>pqr@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id='gen'>Generate excel file</button>
```

After the column is hidden, I am unable to track the ID column. Is there a way out to track the ID column after filtering. e.g. after filtering the output may be, with ID columns and some rows filtered:

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th id='Email'>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
</table>
```

After introducing the hide/unhide coulmn feature, ID column gets hidden too.

Comment: In what way were you 'tracking' the id column, and in what way does it not/no-longer work once they're hidden? What is it you're trying to *do*? You want to create an array *with*, or *without*, the hidden rows' id? And what does your 'filtering' function(s) look like; with the information you're providing, we'd be hard-pressed to make even reasonable guesses at what's going on, and what you want. Unless I'm just tired, and not reading straight...

Comment: @DavidThomas, When 'Generate Excel file' button is clicked, I was capturing all the ID's, then passing those ID's to print data related to that ID in the backend. Now, when I introduce this hide/unhide feature. The ID column now can get hidden too, which made difficult for me to track the IDs. Did I make you clear?

Comment: Not really, no; from the way you describe it in your comment it sounds as if the problem is that people can hide the id column. If so, don't let them hide that one.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes.......not letting people hide the column was the better option...Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If it's hidden, it will still works...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcZA9/1/

```
 $('tr td:first-child').hide();
```

When hiding (hiding **!=** removing) the first column, it still works as expected. Please update the fiddle and be more precise. Based on your question, this is what I think you have asked for.